# Using facebook connect on multiple domains/subdomains

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I started developing a facebook app and I have two sites.

- domain.com (used for marketing purposes and facebook login button is on that page)
- app.domain.com (the app itself)

I have setup a Facebook app, and implemented the SDK so far.

In my app settings I added:

- domain.com,
- www.domain.com
- app.domain.com

Later I call the getLoginUrl method with the redirect_uri parameter

```
$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri' => 'http://app.domain.com', 'display' => 'popup'));
```

I do get the URL, but when I do proceed this URL facebook tells me that the domain app.domain.com is not within my apps domains.

Which is weird since I added it there.

And my call back urls/redirect urls use as well

- app.domain.com
- app.domain.com/mobile

Am I doing something wrong, are am I assuming the wrong?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is **technically** possible to use **Facebook Connect** on multiple domains, there are some limits (5 domains max).

So the key to doing this is **adding all domains** in the **App Domain** field under your app settings.

[image]

The **PROBLEM**, however, is that Facebook only lets you add domains that are derived from your Canvas URL or Site or Page tag URLs, so if you try to enter anything else you get an error that looks like this:

[image]

The **SOLUTION** is to create **App on Facebook**, **Website**, and **Facebook Tab** using the **ADD PLATFORM** button and then put in URLs that point to your other domains. Here is an example of what I mean:

[image]

If you use a **unique domain** for each field you can max out with 5 different domains.  I have tested this technique with up to 3 domains, but i think it should work for all 5.

Note: Facebook admin features change from time to time, so all of this is subject to change